# Part of pan that is not panhandle?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word to refer to the part of a pan that the actual food is in, which may be distinguished from the panhandle?

For example, I would like to say "The [unknown] will heat up faster than the panhandle, so use caution.". Or, "In the final stage of assembly, the panhandle is bolted to the [unknown].".

I'm talking about the round part below :)

[image: pan.png]

Comment: If you use *handle* and *pan* in your examples, they will be perfectly clear.

Comment: Using *panhandle* in the context of a pan instead of simply *handle* just makes everything harder.

Comment: We have pans. Some or most pans have handles. The pan will heat up faster than its handle. A handle is bolted to its pan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *base* of the pan. [Here](https://judge.co.uk/blog/anatomy-of-a-pan.html) is more on "pan anatomy".

*After comment from [user Stuart](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/599989/part-of-pan-that-is-not-panhandle/599991?noredirect=1#comment1510970_599991)*

This is very probably not the most technical description; as they mention what I'll have to call high-sided pans and low-sided ones, it seems safe not to include the sides.  If the sides are not to be included, the term "*body*" seems a good possibility, as the nomenclature found [here](https://www.dunelm.com/product/infinity-copper-base-24cm-frying-pan-1000116101) apparently shows (the copper colour does not extend to the sides).

> Overview
>
> Crafted with a copper base for efficient heat conduction, this Infinity frying pan features a durable stainless steel body, a durable non-stick coating and is suitable for all hob types, excluding induction.

Comment: Interesting. That link doesn't mention the sides separately; I wonder if they are included in "base", or are too unimportant to mention.

Comment: @StuartF I made a modification to my answer.

Comment: I'd say 'base' is incorrect; 'body' works.

Comment: *Body* is also used in this [illustration](https://images.search.yahoo.com/search/images?p=parts+of+a+pan&fr=mcafee&type=E211US105G0&imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Farticle.images.consumerreports.org%2Fprod%2Fcontent%2Fdam%2Fcro%2Fnews_articles%2Fhome_garden%2FCR-BG-Cookware-Pan-Anatomy-Horiz#id=1&iurl=http%3A%2F%2Farticle.images.consumerreports.org%2Fprod%2Fcontent%2Fdam%2Fcro%2Fnews_articles%2Fhome_garden%2FCR-BG-Cookware-Pan-Anatomy-Horiz&action=click)

Answer (score 4):

> "The [unknown] will heat up faster than the panhandle, so use caution."

Idiomatic: "The **pan itself** will heat up faster than the panhandle, so use caution."

OED: **itself**

> **I. Emphatic uses.**
>
> **1.a. Usually in apposition to a noun (as subject, predicate, or object): that particular, the very, that very; alone.**
>
> 1938   New Statesman 25 June 1060/1   *As to the great city itself, no satisfactory redevelopment of it is possible so long as..its overall density is increasing.*
>
> 2003   New Yorker 3 Feb. 89/1   *Dog breeds have changed over time. But has dogginess itself changed?*

Comment: Less commonly used, but ***proper*** can have the same "emphatic,, particularising" sense. For example, [*The hinging bars of the horseshoe - shaped handles run through sockets which are riveted to **the pan proper**.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+pan+proper%22+handle)

Answer (score 3):

For me, using the word "panhandle" is in itself confusing, as its usual meaning is very different. As a noun it refers to a long narrow piece of territory, such as the Florida panhandle that stretches to the west at the northern border of the state.

> The Florida Panhandle is the northwestern part of the U.S. state of Florida; it is >a salient roughly 200 miles long and 50 to 100 miles wide, lying between Alabama on >the north and the west, Georgia on the north, and the Gulf of Mexico to the south. >Its eastern boundary is arbitrarily defined. (Wikipedia)

As a verb, it refers to the action of begging on the street, and gives us the noun "panhandlers"

> CBS News: MODESTO (CBS13) — City leaders in Modesto are turning to the
> public asking for help in reducing the amount of **panhandling** taking
> place throughout the community. Despite posting signs around town,
> officers say **panhandlers** continue to beg and people are still
> giving them money.  Posted 8/17/2017

For the pan itself, why not just use the words "base" and "handle": "the base will heat up faster than the handle"
or
"the pan's base will heat up faster than its handle."

I know my response refers to the use of "panhandle" rather than the query regarding the base, but it might help to clarify the overall approach toward rewording this sentence.